Train a LLM to learn the entropy of the use case
I want to train a LLM (prefered Llama-2-13b) to learn the entropy of german texts - to be specific sports news. I use perplexity as training metric and want to check the training success after the training.
I want to use the fine-tuned model for RAG and I hope, that the fine-tuned model understand the query and context better to give a better answer compared to the orignal model
How can an experiment look like to compare the fine-tuned Llama-2-13b related to the original Llama-2-13b preferably automated for this use case?

Tell us about the loss function, that is, the entropy of each sports article. How exactly are you evaluating the output of one model against another?

That's a good question, because in natrual language you have ambiguousness. I would evaluate the answer by hand or with kind of RAGAS
